# posting json to slim with a form

Tags: php, json, slim

I try to post json with a form using slim.

If I use a rest api, it works. I set this as the body :

```
{
"url": "http://link.com"
}
```

Posting to 'api/generate' :

```
<?php

use Shorty\Models\Link;
use Shorty\Presenters\ErrorPresenter;
use Shorty\Presenters\LinkPresenter;

$app->post('/api/generate', function () use ($app) {

    $payload = json_decode($app->request->getBody());

    if(/*empty($payload) ||*/ !isset($payload->url) || empty(trim($payload->url))){
        $app->response->setStatus(400);

        return $app->response->write(
            new ErrorPresenter('1000', 'A URL is required.')
        );
    }

    if(!filter_var($payload->url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        $app->response->status(400);

        return $app->response->write(
            new ErrorPresenter('1001', 'A valid URL is required.')
        );
    }

    $app->response->setStatus(201);

    $link = Link::where('url', $payload->url)->first();

    if($link){    
        return $app->response->write(
            new LinkPresenter($link)
        );          
    }

    $newLink = Link::create([
        'url' => $payload->url
    ]);

    $newLink->update([
        'code' => $newLink->generateShortCode($newLink->id)
    ]);

    return $app->response->write(
        new LinkPresenter($newLink)
    );  

});
```

It returns what is expected :

```
{"url":"http:\/\/link.com","generated":{"url":"http:\/\/localhost:200\/phpacademy\/shorty\/public\/a","code":"a"}}
```

But I want to send the json through a form. If use this :

```
<form id='userForm'>
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <input type="submit" value="Get link!">
</form>

<!-- where the response will be displayed -->
<div id='response'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userForm').submit(function(){

        // show that something is loading
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        /*
         * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
         * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
         * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
         */
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'api/generate', 
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){

            // show the response
            $('#response').html(data);

        })
        .fail(function() {

            // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;

    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is not working.
I get `{"error":{"code":"1000","message":"A URL is required."}}`.
But I see that "url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.cok" have been posted.

Comment: You are not posting JSON from the form.

Comment: Really ?  How can I post JSON then ?

Comment: With $.ajax contentType : "application/json", I can send json, but it's like that  :[{"name":"url","value":"http://link.com"}].    What I need is [{"url": "http://link.com"}].  How can I get rid of "name-value" ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to send json, but json as "name:value", not the default "name: name, value: value". So I found that :

```
var data = { };
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
    data[this.name] = this.value;
});

data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

I'm building a data object, with each properties as "name:value". Then parse the object into a string.